# Отправка файла на сервер php

Tags: html, jquery

Есть вот такой дизайн формы добавления файла http://joxi.ru/Grqly7PtQkJ8VA. Сделать такой дизайн через форму у меня не получилось и я сделал ее через div. Сложность у меня в том, что я не знаю как мне получить файл который перетащили, и отправить его на сервер. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать. Вот мой код:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000,
    pause: false
});

/* Перетаскивание файла*/
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    var dropZone = $('#dropZone');
    maxFilesSize = 1000000;

    /* Проверяем на поддержки drag and drop*/
    if (typeof(window.FileReader) == 'undefined') {
        dropZone.text('Не поддерживается браузером!');
        dropZone.addClass('error');
    };
    /* Добавляем эффект при навидении*/
    dropZone[0].ondragover = function() {
        dropZone.addClass('hover');
        return false;
    };

    dropZone[0].ondragleave = function() {
        dropZone.removeClass('hover');
        return false;
    };
    dropZone[0].ondrop = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dropZone.removeClass('hover');
        dropZone.addClass('drop');
        var data = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            complete: function (data) {
            }
        });
    };
});
```

```css
#dropZone {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}

#dropZone.hover {
    background: #ddd;
    border-color: #aaa;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#dropZone.error {
    background: #faa;
    border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
 <div id="dropZone">

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет опыта, то лучше воспользоваться каким-то готовым решением. В гугле по запросу «drag and drop file upload jquery» получите массу ссылок на готовые решения с рабочим кодом. Например dropzonejs.com приводит хорошую инструкцию и примеры.